# how can I show "0 Notes" in tumblr when there aren't any notes?

Tags: tumblr

I tried different codes from different themes and google search. Though everything just shows a notification only if there are notes in a post.

So when there aren't notes, i wanted to show "0 notes" - How can I do that

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the first look solution seems to be impossible to output anything if Post has no notes due to [tumblr custom themes docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#notes), but as we shall see, the impossible is possible.

I invented trick to help you with your question.

The main idea of trick is to create special `css class` only if post has *no notes*, after it trick is using content of pseudo-elements to insert necessary text in `.notes` block of post.

Trick requirements: only **tumblr markup** and **css**;

**Tumblr markup:**

```
{block:Text}
<article class="{block:PostNotes}no{/block:PostNotes}nonotes">
    …
    <div class="notes">
        {block:PostNotes}
            {PostNotes}
        {/block:PostNotes}
    </div>
</article>
{/block:Text}
```

**One line css:**

```
article .nonotes .notes:before { content: '0 notes'; }
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put this? I know I can style it to be wherever I want it to be, but where in the HTML should I put it?

Comment: Add `class="{block:PostNotes}no{/block:PostNotes}nonotes"` to containers of your posts inside of each [post-type](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts). To edit your tumblr markup and add additional css use [customize page](http://www.tumblr.com/customize) (“Edit HTMl” to add new tumblr markup and “Add custom CSS” to add your own css)

Comment: Ah, I ended up figuring it out using this method to show if there are any notes without having to go to the post by using Note:Count, and then div's with notes would have a class different than those without, and then I appended "0 notes" to the div without any notes through jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. Starting to think there's no way around this :( except maybe to write your own script to get the NoteCount using the Tumblr API. Hopefully someone will be able to answer this!

Comment: When I wrote this I was using themlr - library which allows you do design your themes on your computer (like a localhost for tumblr) and a month after asking this - when I uploaded the theme on tumblr, the notes did work. I have also tried the API for this, and it does work, but (unless I did it wrong) you need to use JS and therefore it wouldn't be grate for those that disable js